# Resteasy and Spring integration without Spring ContextLoadListener

Tags: spring, resteasy, magnolia

I am using Resteasy and Spring for my project. As Resteasy document said: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.1.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#RESTEasy_Spring_Integration.

I need to add a listener in the web.xml file:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
```

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
```

However, in my project we also used a cms called magnolia, and magnolia also has an implementation for SpringContextLoaderListener. If I put both context listener. The magnolia won't be started when I run the app.

So according to the Resteasy document said:

> If you do not use a Spring ContextLoaderListener to create your bean factories, then you can manually register the RESTeasy BeanFactoryPostProcessor by allocating an instance of org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringBeanProcessor. You can obtain instances of a ResteasyProviderFactory and Registry from the ServletContext attributes org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory and org.jboss.resteasy.spi.Registry. (Really the string FQN of these classes). There is also a org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringBeanProcessorServletAware, that will automatically inject references to the Registry and ResteasyProviderFactory from the Servlet Context. (that is, if you have used RestasyBootstrap to bootstrap Resteasy).

Does anyone knows how can I achieve that without using Resteasy ContextLoaderListener? What do I need to put in my spring applicationContext xml file?

Comment: Will someone knows that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've also had problem with RestEasy `SpringContextListener` (properties placeholders `${...}` weren't processed - [RESTEASY-787](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-787), Spring java config didn't work etc.).
So it's enough to drop RestEasy `SpringContextListener` and use default `org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` or whatever listener you need to. You just have to define Spring bean in your Spring XML configuration like this:

```
<bean class="org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringBeanProcessorServletAware"/>
```

Than RestEasy should work even without their special `SpringContextListener`. It works for me.